# GitLab CI modify postgres service settings

Tags: postgresql, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am using the postgres service in GitLab CI, which I have working fine. The execution is very slow, so there are a few configuration options that I want to modify to speed up the execution.

I put the following in the variables section of my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

> PGOPTIONS: "-c fsync=off -c synchronous_commit=off -c full_page_writes=off"

Based on the output in the logs, these settings are getting picked up, but the database has a fatal error and goes down. Below is what I believe to be the pertinent part of the logs:

```
*** WARNING: Service runner-x8xwaybY-project-xxxx-concurrent-0-postgres-0 probably didn't start properly.
9 Health check error:
10 service "runner-x8xwaybY-project-xxxx-concurrent-0-postgres-0-wait-for-service" timeout
11 Health check container logs:
.
.
.
53 2019-12-31T00:50:53.790047443Z 2019-12-31 00:50:53.789 UTC [46] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
54 2019-12-31T00:50:53.800881648Z 2019-12-31 00:50:53.800 UTC [47] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-12-31 00:50:53 UTC
55 2019-12-31T00:50:53.803321714Z 2019-12-31 00:50:53.803 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
56 2019-12-31T00:50:53.868375914Z  done
57 2019-12-31T00:50:53.868413294Z server started
58 2019-12-31T00:50:53.949656389Z 2019-12-31 00:50:53.949 UTC [62] FATAL:  parameter "fsync" cannot be changed now
59 2019-12-31T00:50:53.949677222Z psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  parameter "fsync" cannot be changed now
```

It seems that the issue is with the fsync option, as the database is already up and running at this point, and that setting cannot be changed without a restart.

How can I change these settings using Gitlab's postgres service?

Answer (score 3):

I found a "solution" to this, and I'm not sure how I missed it before.

I defined the env variable below:

> POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: "--nosync"

This definitely sped up the execution speed. I'm not sure if this essentially behaves the same as disabling all of the config options I mentioned, but regardless it is much faster now.

This doesn't exactly answer my question regarding setting config options, but it gives the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to this, in a [GITLAB FOSS issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/27295) and [Gitlab CI service doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/)

```yaml
services:
    - name: postgres:latest
      command: ["postgres", "-c", "fsync=off", "-c", "synchronous_commit=off", "-c", "full_page_writes=off"]
```